# Weird thing with run and equals method or anything wrong I am doing

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I wrote a multithreaded program in which I am seeing some weird behavior. Below is the code.

```
class Task implements Runnable {
      private Command command;
      private BlockingQueue<Integer> existPool;
      private BlockingQueue<Integer> newPool;
      private int existId;
      private int newId;


      public Task(Command command, BlockingQueue<Integer> pool1, BlockingQueue<Integer> pool2) {
            this.command = command;
            this.existPool = pool1;
            this.newPool = pool2;
      }

public void run() {
    if(command.getDataCriteria().equals(PDSLnPConstants.DATA_CRITERIA_PREVIOUS)) {
    try {
        // Getting existing id from the pool
        existId = existPool.take();
        attributeGetSetMethod(existId);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        getLogger().log(LogLevel.ERROR, e.getLocalizedMessage());
    } finally {
        // And releasing that existing ID for re-use
        existPool.offer(existId);       
    }
    }

//Something wrong happening here
else if(command.getDataCriteria().equals(PDSLnPConstants.DATA_CRITERIA_NEW)) {
    try {
        // Getting new id from the pool
        newId = newPool.take();
        attributeGetSetMethod(newId);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        getLogger().log(LogLevel.ERROR, e.getLocalizedMessage());
    } finally {
        // And releasing that new ID for re-use
        newPool.offer(newId);   
    }
    }
}
}
```

From the below code. above run method is getting called.

```
    for (int i = startRange; i <= endRange; i++) {
    availableExistingIds.add(i);
    }

    for (int n = newStartRange; n <= newEndRange; n++) {
    availableNewIds.add(n);
    }

    BlockingQueue<Integer> existIdPool = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer>(11, false, availableExistingIds);
    BlockingQueue<Integer> newIdPool = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer>(21, false, availableNewIds);


    GUID_ID_MAPPING = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>>();
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long endTime = startTime + (durationOfRun*60*1000L);

    // Running for particular duration of time
    while(System.currentTimeMillis() <= endTime) {
    Command nextCommand = getNextCommandToExecute();
    Task nextCommandExecutorRunnable = new Task(nextCommand, existIdPool, newIdPool);
    executorService.submit(nextCommandExecutorRunnable); // Submit it for execution
    }
```

**Problem Statement:-**

One weird thing that I have just noticed is- In the below else if loop if you see my above code in run method `if the command.getDataCriteria() is Previous` then also it gets entered in the else if block(which is for `New`) which shouldn't be happening right as I am doing a `.equals` check? Why this is happening?

```
else if(command.getDataCriteria().equals(PDSLnPConstants.DATA_CRITERIA_NEW)) {
```

**Update:-**

Below is the image from my console.[image]

in which you can clearly see, `dataCriteria was New` and it went to `PREVIOUS block`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code is really

```
if(command.getDataCriteria().equals(PDSLnPConstants.DATA_CRITERIA_PREVIOUS)) {
   ...
else if(command.getDataCriteria().equals(PDSLnPConstants.DATA_CRITERIA_NEW)) {
   ...
}
```

Then it is not possible that both `...`s can get executed.  It doesn't depend on synchronization, threads, a bad equals implementation, or anything else.  There's something else you don't understand (is it really the same run() call that is in both?), or possibly something I don't understand about your problem statement (which is pretty confusing).

Comment: I need to execute only one block depending on the commands Criteria.

Comment: The code as given is guaranteed to execute at most one of those two blocks, by the semantics of Java's `else`.

Comment: My scenario is something like this- `If the command.getDataCriteria() contains Previous then each thread always needs to use UNIQUE ID between 1 and 1000 and release it for reusing again.
Else if the command.getDataCriteria() contains New then each thread always needs to use UNIQUE ID between 2000 and 3000 and release it for reusing again.`

Comment: Your code looks ok for that, so show us the evidence that you think something is going wrong.

Comment: Can you please let me know what kind of evidence I should provide here? Please let me know, I will try to add those things in my code and put it back here.

Comment: Well, what made you think there was a problem in the first place?  Show us the evidence it was in both branches.  I suspect we will find a bug in that evidence.

Comment: I was debugging my code slowly and slowly trying to reproduce the problem. And at the same time I was checking what is the value in `command.getDataCriteria()` and in which block it went automatically. So by this I found out, `command.getDataCriteria()` returns previous but it went to else if block.

Comment: Just updated my question with an image. Let me know if you need anything else from me.

Comment: So that's not executing on *both* sides if the if/else.  It's just executing on the *wrong* side of the if/else.  Then you either have a bug in `equals`, `DATA_CRITERIA_PREVIOUS` isn't what you think it is, or some other thread is updating `dataCriteria` in parallel.

Comment: If I make run method as `synchronized`, then it will help me in anyway?

Comment: Unlikely.  You need to put both the reader (the code you've shown) and the writer (which is where?) under the same lock.  Putting the reader under a lock by itself won't help at all.

Comment: My theory is that `getNextCommandToExecute` isn't returning a new `Command` each time.  If it reuses `Command`s, then the new command overwrites the old command while the `Task` is still reading the old `Command`.  Use a new `Command` each time and the problem might go away.